# Limited range when copying from excel VBA to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am developing a macro that transfers a range of cells from excel to word bookmark. The problem I am having is that not the whole of the range I selected is transfered. Not sure if there is a limit to how big the range can be? Also want the transfered content to autofit to the word documents margins?

The code I have so far is:

```
'Name of the existing Word doc.
Const stWordReport As String = "Exporting a Table to a Word Document 2.docx"    

'Word objects.
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdbmRange As Word.Range

'Excel objects.
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim rnReport As Range
'Dim Table1 As Range

Dim coluna As Integer
coluna = Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(1, Worksheets("Planilha1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Table1 = Worksheets("Planilha1").Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(16, coluna))

'Initialize the Excel objects.
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
Set rnReport = wsSheet.Range("Table1")

'Initialize the Word objects.
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\" & stWordReport)
Set wdbmRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Report").Range

'Turn off screen updating.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy the report to the clipboard.
rnReport.Copy

'Select the range defined by the "Report" bookmark and paste in the report from clipboard.
With wdbmRange
    .Select
    .PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
                  DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
                  Placement:=wdInLine, _
                  DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

'Save and close the Word doc.
With wdDoc
    .Save
    .Close
End With

'Quit Word.
wdApp.Quit

'Null out your variables.
Set wdbmRange = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing

'Clear out the clipboard, and turn screen updating back on.
With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox "The report has successfully been " & vbNewLine & _
       "transferred to " & stWordReport, vbInformation
```

I expect the content on the word document to have the same formatting as the excel one and to be fitted to the page.

Comment: What size range (rows/columns) is giving you problems? FWIW Word does have a maximum column limit. As I recall, it's 56. But given the maximum page size of a Word document, it also makes no sense for Word to support more columns than that as they can't be rendered in a reasonable manner. Word can't break pages horizontally the way Excel can...

Comment: I have filled the cells from column one to column thirteen and only five columns appear on the word document

Comment: Without more information about the original Excel content and the result you're getting it's not possible to formulate a useful answer...

Answer (score 0):

Word's maximum column count is 63; there is no set row limit. In any event, since you are pasting what you've copied as a picture, the table limits aren't relevant. I suspect the real issue is with how you're determining coluna. Try:

```
'Initialize the Excel objects.
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
Set rnReport = wsSheet.Range("Table1")

coluna = wsSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
Table1 = wsSheet.Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(16, coluna))
```